# A shared component's css is not applied when target specific platforms in Ionic 5 and Angular 9

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm doing an application using Ionic 5 and [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides).

I have created a shared component with the **ion-slides** logic to use it anywhere. On the `.scss` file I have added a few custom styles and they are working properly. The issue arises when I target specific platforms like **md** and **ios**.

```
<ion-slides pager>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let i of images">
    <img [src]="i" />
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Style:

```
/*
 * All Platforms
 */

// Working =)
ion-slides {
  --bullet-background-active: white;
}

/*
 * Material Design
 */

// Not working =(
.md {
  ion-slides {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 12px 26px;
  }
}

/*
 * iOS
 */

// Not working =(
.ios {
  ion-slides {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 16px;
  }
}
```

I have tried with `::deep` and `::before` on each platform and no luck. I have also tried with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on the component's decorator.

I don't understand why its specific styles for each platform are not applied.

**Note**: Just for testing, I moved the logic and styles of my slides's component to the parent, and the styles for each platform are applied correctly, so the issue arises when using this slides's component in another component, as a child.

My goal is to be able to change the `box-shadow` of my slides for each platform while using this component as a child of another.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `:host` worked for me. So it would look like this:

```
.ion-slides {
  --bullet-background-active: white;
}


.md :host .ion-slides {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 12px 26px;
}

.ios :host .ion-slides {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 16px;
}
```

Here's the forum thread that lead me to this solution.

- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-platform-specific-style-in-component/138896/4